# Giving a background for each <div> and/or section

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html css, and i'm encountering some difficulties.
So i have a div and an article and i do want to give them a background, so if you charge the page, you'll have a background with a header etc, and if you scroll a bit you have the article with his own background and then a footer.

```
<body>
    <div class="background">        
        <div id="bloc">
            <p class="menu"><a href="#">Mes voyages</a></p>
            <p class="menu"><a href="#">Mes photos</a></p>
            <p class="menu"><a href="#">Mes conseils</a></p>
        </div>      

    </div>      

    <article class="article">
            <h1>Présentation</h1>
    </article>

    <footer class="foot">
        <p>Me contacter:<br/>
        <a href="lol@hotmail.fr">E-mail</a>
        </p>
        </footer>

</body>
```

I'll give you a sample of my css too :

```
.background {
    background-image: url('images/back.png');
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 700px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bloc {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    position:absolute;
    top:15%;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius:15px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

article {
    background-image:url('images/article.jpg');
    height:1080px;
}
```

I don't really understand why it does not work ?
Oh ! And when i resize the page below a certain size, the text scrolls out of the border of the "menu" class.

Thank you for your help. I've tried to make it clear^^

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! For specific styling questions like this, consider including a jsfiddle or a snippet of the issue so people can assist you more efficiently.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ywep6jLk/1/   Heres a fiddle, i dont understand what you want exactly

Comment: what did you mean exactly with "it does not work"? In my opinion the question is not really clear

Comment: Is this the kind of behavior you are looking for? http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/ The Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript framework will also help you resolve your browser re-size issues as it is a responsive framework (adapts layout for changes in screen size).

Comment: Yes something like this.
Tried to make it clear but i'm not English native so it's a bit hard.

Comment: In that case use the Bootstrap library if you can: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<article class="article">
        <h1 id="header">Présentation</h1>
</article>

.background{
background-image: url('images/back.png');
background-size: cover;
display: block;
height: 700px;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#header{
position:fixed;}
```